# How to include the trace based on condition in Dash-Plotly

Tags: plotly-dash

I have stacked graph with multiple traces (for Priority High, Low), the request data comes from CSV file which may or may not have a priority (say High). I add the traces to the graph but it throws exception if we dont get High priority requests in CSV.

```
figure_priority={
           'data': [
                    trace2,
                     trace1,
```

What I did is conditional check to verify priority is present in the dataframe and then returning related figure i.e.

```
if High in Col.list && Low in Col.list: 
  trace2 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[('Number', 'High')]
  trace1 = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[('Number', 'Low')]
                 figure_priority={
                'data': [
                
                    trace2,
                     trace1,
elif Low in Col.list :
trace = go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[('Number', 'Low')]
          figure_priority={
                'data': [
                    trace2,
```

but I think there would be easier way to do this logic, what happens when I get High, Low and Medium priorities
How would I check if specific group is in Columns and add traces to stacked chart based on content..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a for loop and fill up a list of traces:

```
types = ['High', 'Medium', 'Low']
traces = []
for type in types:
    if type in Col.list:
        traces.append(go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[('Number', type)])
```

Comment: Works , I added few lines of code to get what I was looking at, will add below for future use. Thank..

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, here is code snippet with color for stacked bar, any optimization is more than welcome..

```
        app_type=[('High','#7a5195'),('Low','#ffa600'),('Medium','#ffa6CC')]
        traces =[]
        for app_type,color in app_types:
            if app_type in str(pv.columns.tolist())
                traces.append(
                    go.Bar(x=pv.index, y=pv[('Number', app_type)], text=pv[('Number', app_type)], textposition = 'auto',
                            opacity=0.8,
                            marker={"color":color,
                            "line": {
                                "color": "#cdcdcd",
                                "width": 2,
                            },
                    },            
                        name=app_type)
                )

        figure_new={
                "data":
                    traces
                ,
                 'layout': go.Layout(
```